# Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-US)

```
• Flutter version 3.0.0 at C:\src\flutter

• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

• Framework revision ee4e09cce0 (1 year, 2 months ago), 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700

• Engine revision d1b9a6938a

• Dart version 2.17.0

• DevTools version 2.12.2
```

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)

```
• Android SDK at C:\Android2

• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0

• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android2

• ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Android2\platform-tools\adb.exe

• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

X Android license status unknown.

  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.

  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

```
• Chrome at C:\Users\ADVANCED\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.0.2)

```
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise

• Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.0.28803.202

• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.0
```

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)

```
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

• Flutter plugin version 44.0.1

• Dart plugin version 191.8593

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
```

[√] VS Code (version 1.76.2)

```
• VS Code at C:\Users\ADVANCED\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

• Flutter extension version 3.68.0
```

[√] Connected device (3 available)

```
• SM G9880 (mobile) • emulator-5558 • android-x64    • Android 9 (API 28)

• Windows (desktop) • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]

• Chrome (web)      • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.199
```

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

From Android Studio you can find below Image

[image: Go To SDK tools]

You just check the box what version you need.
then download and restart the Android studio
it will working well, let me know if you face any problem ,

Answer (score 0):

Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences ).
In the left panel, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates .
Be sure that Automatically check for updates is checked, then select a channel from the drop-down list (see figure 1).
Click Apply or OK.

Method 2

In the left panel, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Sdk tool search for android toolchain then check its box and select ok and a install window will appear.